# image embedded in email HTML template - Flask-mail ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-mail

I tried to send a response email from the HTML template that includes an image on the header.  If I send HTML without image attachment there is no error but it is a text email like. I searched and test for a couple of days, no success.

Flask-email snippet is

```
msg = Message(form.title.data, recipients=['emial@gmail.com'])
msg.html = render_template('mail_temp/file.html')
with open('/home/daniel/PycharmProjects/Sitio/blue/static/pictures/ribbon.jpg', 'rb') as fp:
    msg.attach('ribbon.jpg', 'image/jpg', fp.read(), 'inline', headers={'Content-ID': 'ribbon'})
mail.send(msg)
```

HTML template include image in:

```
<td> <img src="cid:ribbon"/> </td>
```

The issue seems to happen in the parameter for Message. Attach method.  I found a similar question and response but 2 years old, maybe the method changes it.

Thanks in advance.

```
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/Sitio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/Sitio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/daniel/PycharmProjects/Sitio/blue/site/routes.py", line 220, in contactme
    mail.send(msg)
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/Sitio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 492, in send
    message.send(connection)
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/Sitio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 427, in send
    connection.send(self)
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/Sitio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 190, in send
    message.as_bytes() if PY3 else message.as_string(),
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/Sitio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 385, in as_bytes
    return self._message().as_bytes()
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/Sitio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 371, in _message
    for key, value in attachment.headers:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
``
```

Comment: `msg.html = render_template('mail_temp/file.html')` this line makes no sence. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: This is the template for email, actually if config like `msg.attach('ribbon.jpg', 'image/jpg', fp.read())` the email template and the image are send but it is not include in html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns that there are two issues in msg.attach parameters:

1. headers is a list instead dictionary;
2. Contend-ID tag is enclosed in `< >`

```
with open('/home/daniel/PycharmProjects/Sitio/blue/static/pictures/ribbon.jpg', 'rb') as fp:
    msg.attach('ribbon.jpg', 'image/jpg', fp.read(), 'inline', headers=[[Content-ID','<ribbon>']])
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me too. Great help OP!